# Enumerable Range Add .5

Tags: c#, enumerable.range

I'm trying to create a list that should generate the following:

```
1,1.5,2,2.5,3
```

Here is the code that I made that supposed to generate the list

```
var rng = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => x / 10f);
```

I am currently using this statement but it seems that it generates

```
0.1,0.2
```

What should be the formula I use to make it as 1, 1.5, 2?

Comment: How about dividing by 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rng = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => 0.5 + x / 2f);
```

This will give you a list: `1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, ..` starting at 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be your goal, why divide by 10?

```
var rng = Enumerable.Range(2/*START NUMBER*/, 5/*POSITION FROM START*/).Select(x => x / 2f);
```

(5 if you want to stop at 3, if you put 12 you stop at 7)

Comment: got it, thanks, my bad, i'll edit my answer. I was thinking on it by matematical point of wiew :)